# What is a good pattern for array template compatibility?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, flexible-array-member

I would like to create objects having a variable-length array of elements, and have them be compatible in a base/derived-class sense.  In C, one could put an indeterminate array at the end of a `struct` and then just malloc the object to contain the full array:

```
struct foo {
    int n;
    double x[];
} ;

struct foo *foo1 = (foo *)malloc( sizeof( foo ) + sizeof( double[4] ) );
struct foo *foo2 = (foo *)malloc( sizeof( foo ) + sizeof( double[100] ) );
```

In c++, it seems like you could do:

```
template <unsigned I>
class foo {
public:
    int n;
    double x[I];
} ;
```

but:

```
auto foo1 = new foo<4>( );
auto foo2 = new foo<100>( );

if (foo1 == foo2) cerr << "incompatible pointers";
```

You can do it with a common base class, but is that necessary?  I just want to use `foo1` and `foo2`, where each object knows the length of its array.

---

My application is for an ESP32 microcontroller running FreeRTOS.  It has limited, non-virtual RAM and a slightly complicated allocation system because of differing capabilities of various chunks of memory (some is slower, some can't contain executable code, some can't be accessed by DMA, etc.)  So allocating multiple chunks for pieces of an object (for example, by using `std::vector` for the array of `double` at the end) becomes complicated.

I know the length of the `double` array at object construction time, but I would like the header and the array to be in a single allocated block of memory (so it can have the characteristics I need for it to have later).

The C-style way of doing it would be fine, but it would be nice to have C++ features like iteration over the array (for various objects, which will each have different numbers of `double`s). Plus, a native C++ solution would allow me to have objects in the `x[]` array, instead of fooling around with placement `new` in raw allocated memory.  So, for example:

```
auto a[] = { new foo<5>( ), new foo<10>( ), new foo<15>( ) };

for (auto i : a)
    for (auto j : i.x)
        cout << log10( j );    // prints 40 logs of doubles
```

(I expect that's got C++ syntax errors, but hopefully it communicates the idea.  I can figure out the syntax for that, if I could get all the `foo`s into a common container.)

Comment: This is what `std::vector` is for.

Comment: Why not `std::vector`? I presume you have a reason for it.

Comment: If you want to compare two pointers of two different types (quite bizarre) you can cast them to `void*`. If you want to compare the two objects (get rid of that useless `new`) you must tell the compiler how you intend to compare the two different size arrays, providing a templated `operator==` for your family of classes

Comment: `foo<4>` and `foo<100>` are two stuff. You need to learn what template is. Use `std::vector>` instead.

Comment: `std::vector` would be fine, except that in my application, the array size is known at construction, so `std::vector` is heavier than I need.  Further, I believe there'd be an additional indirection to get from `foo*` to `foo->x[0]`, when all that is actually necessary is an index off `foo*`.  This may not matter too much, until you're working on a microcontroller with not too much memory, not too sophisticated memory management, and memory with special characteristics (e.g. DMA capable or not).  Adding `std::vector` there means you have to have special allocators, on top of the indirection.

Comment: Hi. If the size is known at compile time just use `std::array`. If you insist on using your structure then just do `foo1->x == foo2->x`. Also don't worry about optimizing away the indirection. The compiler will optimize it anyway

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  I need various bits of information in the pre-array header (so a bare `std::array` wouldn't be enough) but maybe it gets me closer.  And I suppose worst case, I can have a common base class for the template.  It's a bit of extra typing, but not the end of the world.

Comment: Ah, unless maybe I made the `std::array<double,I>` the base class?  And put the extra info at the end?  That makes it harder for the compiler to find the extra "header" info, but it shouldn't be significantly different -- no extra indirections, anyway.

Comment: Don't use `std` classes as base classes. You will be in a world of pain. Maye expand your question to explain what exactly is your need so we can point you in the right direction

Comment: Surely you mean “prints 40 logs of doubles”?

Comment: Two options: first, work with a heterogeneous container such as std::tuple, and abd pick any of the for_each functions on SO. Second: use a base class or type erssure (e.g. std::function) to obtain a homogeneous type which can be stored in a vector, and looped over in the standard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a low-level C++ developer, I understand exactly what you need, and sadly, there is no replacement for flexible array members in standard C++, with or without templates. You have to keep using flexible array members via compiler extensions.

They are not included in the language since in their current form, they are essentially a hack. They don't do well with inheritance or composition.

The problem with templates is that, the flexible array version has a common type of arrays of all sizes. That means you can place them in arrays, have non-template functions take them as parameters etc:

```
foo* make_foo(int n);

foo* foos[] = { make_foo(1); make_foo(2); make_foo(3); }; // ok

void take_foo(foo*);
```

With the template version, types `foo<1>` and `foo<2>` are completely unrelated, so you cannot put them in arrays or have non-template functions that take them:

```
template <int N>
foo<N>* make_foo();

auto foos[] = { make_foo<1>(), make_foo<2>(), make_foo<3>() }; // ill-formed

template <int N>
void take_foo(foo<N>*);
```

`std::array` won't help in this discussion, and inheriting from one will still have the problem of having unrelated types.

However, since this is still C++ (albeit non-standard), you can at least have *some* additional niceties:

```
template <class T>
struct flex_array {
  int n;
  T data[];

  T* begin() { return &data[0]; }
  T* end() { return begin() + n; }
};


void iterate(flex_array<double>& f) {
    for (double j : f) {
        cout << log10(j); // print however many doubles are in f
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's not good news, but at least it saves me some time thrashing around with templates!  Thanks!

Comment: I fooled around with this some more, and mostly got it working the way I wanted.  Here is a JDoodle with the code (and some debug framework): https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/4zhq .  The `flex_array<T>` works mostly like a `std::array<T,N>` but the array length isn't part of the type signature, so you can pass different-length arrays of `T`s to functions, etc.  If I can work out perfect forwarding, I expect to be able to construct arrays in place, and that'll be great!

Comment: I haven't read it fully, but why do you have this? `static const T *tp = 0; static const size_t ts = (const char *)(tp + 1) - (const char *)(tp);` Are you trying to get `sizeof(T)`?

Comment: You could also post the whole thing to the code review stack exchange for some thorough feedback.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get `sizeof(T)`, accounting for the possibility (?) that the compiler would align `T`s in an array with padding for alignment purposes.  (I did some simple testing, and it didn't seem to be an issue, but I'm not a c++ language lawyer.  It seemed like `&T[1] - &T[0]` should give you the size you need to allocate if you're going to be telling the compiler that there's a useable array of `T`s at some address.

Comment: Padding bytes are accounted for in `sizeof`, so you would get the same size, except without undefined behavior. Arithmetic on the `nullptr` is UB IIRC. Since 0 size arrays are non-standard, how your overall flex_array is aligned would be implementation defined here, but I would expect it to be as if you had a non-zero sized array, so it's okay.